# How can add specific relationship or query types as an attribute on a Bookshelf Model?

Tags: bookshelf.js

I've been using KnexJS for a while, and want to transition to BookshelfJS, as my model classes on the server side are starting to get a little hairy, and why re-invent the wheel.

For a lot of my API server, what I want to do is pre-fetch a list of related models (a document has many and belongs to many editors) without necessarily pre-fetching the whole thing. Ideally, I'd end up with

```
document = {
    id: 1
    body: 'foobar'
    editor_ids: [1, 2]
}
```

Now, I can do this by doing editors: belongsToMany(Profiles) on the Document definition, and then doing a fetch().withRelated(['editors']), but the problem there is that it returns the full Profile object on the fetch.

This generates an extraneous join (`documents_editors join editors on editors.id = documents_editors.editor_id`) that's not needed, and to conform to the spec my client app expects, (the IDs embedded and then the profiles themselves added later in the JSON response only optionally, and actually in practice never, because profiles tend to get cached and loaded elsewhere), I have to manually shove the editor_ids attribute in there by parsing through Document.relations, which also adds (a tiny tiny bit) of extra time.

So, ultimately, I can do what I want but it's not elegant. Ideally, there's something in BookshelfJS where I could do something like

```
Document = bookshelf.Model.extend
    tableName: 'documents'
    fancyValue: ->
        @rawQuery 'select editor_id from documents_editors where document_id = ?', [@id]
```

Or build a knex-style query in there. I know in the above particular use case, a raw query is kind of overkill, but I do actually have some more annoying queries to run as well. I track user-community memberships, and permission grants on documents to communities, which means I use a postgres-style CTE to do something like

```
 with usergroups as
  (
    select communities.id from communities inner join edges
    on communities.id = edges.parent_id and edges.parent_type = 'communities'
      and edges.child_id = ? and edges.child_type = 'profiles'
      and edges.type = 'grant: comment'
  )
  select distinct documents.id as parent_id, 'documents' as parent_type
  from documents inner join edges
    on edges.parent_id = documents.id and edges.parent_type = 'documents'
    and edges.type = 'grant: edit'
    and documents.type = 'collection'
    where (edges.child_type = 'profiles' and edges.child_id = ?) or
     (edges.child_type = 'communities' and edges.child_id in (select id from usergroups))
```

(which finds all the documents of type 'collection' that the user in question can edit, either because they were directly added as an editor or because they belong to a community which was granted edit access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A description of how I approached this problem can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/ericeslinger/a83e74501e9901c8b795

which basically amounts to "I wrote some custom behaviors and threw them into a subclass of bookshelf.Model that all of my application Model objects inherits from".